# Drawable set to Spinner background stretches out

Tags: android

You can see my layout here, where the `Spinner` with the drawable `ic_menu_preferences` set to its background is stretched out relative to the `ImageButton` with the same drawable

[image]

How can I add a drawable to the `Spinner` background without stretching out the drawable?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/scannerSettingsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/scannerButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textOn="SCAN"
            android:textOff="STOP"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the Java code

```
dropdownMenu = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdownMenu);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("");
list.add("list 2");
list.add("list 3");
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
dropdownMenu.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012701/spinners-background-image-appears-stretched)

The background image takes all the given space - 1/3 of the the LinearLayout width. If you don’t want it to stretch, you could create a drawable layout, e.g. drawable/my_sort_icon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_sort_by_size"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

and use it as a background image in your Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/my_sort_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"/>
```